# Namespace binding in RDFLib

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib, turtle-rdf

In the following minimal test case:

```py
from rdflib import Graph, Namespace, Literal, RDF

base = "http://test.com/ns"
foobar = Namespace("http://test.com/ns#")
g = Graph(base=base)
g.bind('foobar', foobar)

g.add((foobar.something, RDF.type, Literal('Blah')))
g.add((foobar.something, foobar.contains, Literal('a property')))

g.add((foobar.anotherthing, RDF.type, Literal('Blubb')))
g.add((foobar.anotherthing, foobar.contains, Literal('another property')))

print(g.serialize(format='turtle').decode("utf-8"))
```

I get

```
@base <http://test.com/ns> .
@prefix foobar: <http://test.com/ns#> .

<#anotherthing> a "Blubb" ;
    ns1:contains "another property" .

ns1:something a "Blah" ;
    ns1:contains "a property" .
```

what I'd expecte is more like

```
@base <http://test.com/ns> .
@prefix foobar: <http://test.com/ns#> .

<#anotherthing> a "Blubb" ;
    foobar:contains "another property" .

<#something> a "Blah" ;
    foobar:contains "a property" .
```

So either there is something I fundamentally don't understand about RDFLib and how to use namespaces, or there's something funky going on.
Any thoughts, anyone?

Comment: Strange indeed. It would not be a surprise if the result simply ignored the custom name, but this kind of output is not valid.

Comment: I've been experimenting a bit, and it turns out that the problem seems to persist **only** if base and prefix point to the same URI. To me, this seems still a weird behaviour, but a workaround would then be to leave out the base alltogether, or not to bind the prefix. (I'll post an answer as soon as I know more, for future people with the same issue)

Comment: Seems like a good idea to post the issue to the creators of RDFLib, if there is a bug in the implementation.

Comment: You're totally right, I did open an issue on GitHub :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `base` declaration also needs the final has or slash in it.

So try `g = Graph(base="http://test.com/ns#")` and everything will work fine

OR

Try without any base in this case.

Either will give you valid results. Yes there is something odd going on deep inside RDFlib with the base, but only when it's not ended with # or /.

By the way, your triples are a bit invalid: you can't use `rdf:type` with a range value of a literal, it has to be an `rdf:Class` instance.

Comment: typo?: has os shash --> hash or slash

Comment: Yes, it should read "final hash or slash in it".